# How to copy up to a particular character (including that character) in every line using Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex, copy-paste, find-and-replace, clipboard

I have a text file with about 10000 lines of text. The text file is in JSON format. I want to cut (& keep in clipboard) the data found after the ':' colon symbol.

```
{
"Cust_Data": {
"First Name": "John",
"Last Name": "Doe",
"Email Address": "John.Doe@Lorem.Ipsum",
"City": "New York City",
"State": "New York"
}.
"Cust_Account": {
"Account Number": "57235286096572",
"Branch Code": "US0163GR",
"Routing Number": "CHAUSA56325",
"Bank Name": "Bank of America",
"SWIFT Code": "SW356FGH6534567",
"Date of Remittance": "04-30-2005"
}.
.....
.....
.....
```

This is what I want as the result:

```
    {
    "Cust_Data": {
    "First Name": 
    "Last Name": 
    "Email Address": 
    "City":
    "State":
    }.
    "Cust_Account": {
    "Account Number":
    "Branch Code":
    "Routing Number":
    "Bank Name": 
    "SWIFT Code":
    "Date of Remittance": 
    }.
........
........
........
```

The clipboard should contain the data that is removed from the text file.

Please suggest me an idea to achieve this in Notepad ++ using Regex, or any other options.

Comment: Replace: `:[^{\n]*` by `:`

Comment: @Luuk That doesn't copy it to the clipboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Go to the `Mark` tab
- Find what: `^.+\:\s\K(".+)`
- Select `Wrap around`
- Search mode: `Regular Expression`
- Press <kbd>Mark All</kbd>
- Press <kbd>Copy Marked Text</kbd>

**Mark tab**

[image]

- Go to the `Replace` tab
- OReplace with: Leave it empty
- Press <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Replace tab**

[image]

The marked texts will be removed from the original file, but clipboard will contain them all. You can then copy them to another file.

Comment: The capture group is useless and there're no needs to escape the colon.

Comment: @Toto you are 100% about both.